# Render HTML Content from rich text field to page

Tags: html, richtextarea

I store raw HTML code in a rich text field in the backend. I query it out in the controller and try to render it as HTML in a VF page. It displays the whole HTML code, it dosent render itself as HTML. I have used escape = false in the output text. This was working properly when the field was a long text area. Please provide me a way to get it to 'escape' once again.

Comment: why don't you try `<apex:outputField>` ?

Comment: or you can go harder, use a hidden output field in visual force page, get value of the html field via JS, and apply that to certain page position. That's harder, but more flexible

Comment: You should post some code if you want a precise answer to why things aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-render the html code with JavaScript as shown in the example below. `Rich_Text__c` is a RichText field containing raw html code. Through jQuery the span tag is replaced by a div element with the raw html code created by jQuery. Now you can see rendered html in page.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="RichTextController" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span id="inputtxt"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#inputtxt").html($('<div/>').html("{!myText}").text());
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class RichTextController {
    public String myText {get;set;}
    public RichTextController(){
        Book__c abook = [SELECT Rich_Text__c FROM Book__c where Id = 'a0Ii000000gKbw5']; 
        myText = abook.Rich_Text__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not pass security review if its appexchange app

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks for your comment, I have updated my answer.

Comment: This won't pass either.You have to HTML and JSENCODE your getter merge field

Comment: Of course it can pass the Security Review. Rich Text fields are safe to render unescaped.

Comment: I have tried and did not work for me

Comment: @NickKahn what is not working for you? Can you please post a Question with your code?

Comment: This wont have any problems in the security review as long as the field is of type richtext field and you make the setter private.